# Positional Join and referential Integrity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below diagram of how a referential integrity between rows in a textfile should be joined by using a positional join.

The text files look like this:

I have had to insert each row from the text file into its own table depending on the value of the first column. I was wondering if anyone can make any sense of this using the diagram and also the notepad file. The I26, I28, I27 and I99 are positional join and its the one I am having a problem getting my head around.

If anyone has done this please could you provide a possible solution in terms of doing a join for all 4 values mentioned above.

I haven't got enough knowledge around the subject matter, kinda been dumped with it so I am happy to take your own assumptions around how the joins should be.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You could split the file in several files for each code. Then load each file into a table that corresponds with that code. For example a PowerShell script could be used to split such file.

Comment: Do you have this tables, or you need to create them somehow?

Comment: I have the above text file posted, which i then use SSIS conditional Split to put each first column value to its own table. I need to be able to put the data back together using the diagram which define the referential integrity. i.e i27 on the notepad the next two proceeding i28 belong to that i27

Comment: What do you mean by "Put the data back together?"  If you already have the tables created by SSIS and you know the `join` conditions what is stopping you creating the primary and foreign key relationships with SQL?

Comment: Thats the thing, the joins are positional, so If you look at the diagram (which I don't fully understand) the I26 is a parent of I27, the I27 is parent of I28 so its likes a triangular join which i dont know how to join on. for each I27 there are two I28 which are their child etc but not sure how to represent this when querying it.

Comment: So, what do you need? I guess for now it is a very broad question. Is there any table structures in your DB, or the tables must be created? How this tables must be joined? I know about diagram, but what will be PK what FK etc?

Comment: I have been asked to separate each row into its own table by look at the first column value.  The primary and foreign key would be the combination of the second and third column I would imagine coupled with some row number function to identify the positional value but not sure how to do this if it's in separate tables